# how to estimate the system RAM size requirement for ELK

Tags: elastic-stack

I want to estimate the hardware requirement (RAM) for elastic search and kibana.

Assume i'm deploying Elastic and Kibana on same server as one node cluster. And i want to estimate the Minimum RAM size using injection rate vs query rate?